# Run php in background

Tags: linux, ssh, dedicated-server

I connect to a dedicated server with SSH. Next I'm trying to execute in php -d max_execution_time[=0] -f index.php . How can I close (even shut down) my local machine, but my php script on remote server should continue working?

Answer (score 4):

Or with screen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

```
screen -A -m -d -S whatever ./yourphpscriptlauncher.sh
```

The cool +, with:

```
screen -r whatever
```

You are again at your script ;)

Comment: +1 for screen. It's useful in other situations too. Alternatively try tmux which is similar to screen

Comment: i use screen on all my production machines to run all sort of scripts (php and python)

Answer (score 1):

Run your php script like that: `ssh user@machine "nohup php -d max_execution_time[=0] -f index.php &"`

Comment: This won't work as written, because when you run a command as an argument to SSH, no TTY is allocated. nohup requires a TTY to detach from. It will work fine if you SSH in, get an interactive shell, and then run the command through nohup, however. The best way to do this non-interactively is probably to submit a command to `atd` with `at now` that runs immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways listed here:

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/10/16/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-the-background/